# Is it possible to extract data from handwritten invoices using the Azure invoice model?

Tags: data-extraction, azure-form-recognizer

I am first time use azure service. And want to extract handwritten data from invoices using form recognizer invoice model?

But in documentation there was no information weather azure form recognizer invoice model extract data from handwritten document or not.

I am tring to extract data from invoices using key-value pair here invoices can be handwritten even that situation I expect response with high confidence score.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you out: https://medium.com/version-1/data-extraction-using-azure-form-recognizer-custom-model-python-sdk-ec40bb89a611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invoice model also supports handwritten data. Here is a sample screenshot of the handwritten form used for analysis. I hope it helps.

[image]